# How to use the RandomNumberGenerator within llvm?

Tags: llvm

I was hoping someone can give me an example as to how to use the [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1RandomNumberGenerator.html) class within `LLVM`. All of the examples I am able to find seem to use outdated methods.

I would like to be able to create a RNG within a pass that can be overridden with the '-rng-seed' parameter.

How can this value be accessed if it was provided as a parameter, and how to create the value if it was not provided as a parameter?

Also, I understand that a single RNG is not meant to be shared between threads for a single module. If I am running multiple passes on a module, can they share the same generated RNG?

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of those outdated examples? I might have to update my answer, since it's an API call I almost never use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RandomNumberGenerator` class has a private constructor (check its doc and the source file under `llvm/lib/Support/RandomNumberGenerator.cpp`), so the only way (that I know of, at least) to get a hold of an instance is via [`Module`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html)'s `createRNG` method.

So, assuming that you have `llvm:Function` pass (and using C++11):

```
bool runOnFunction(llvm::Function &CurFunc) override {
  auto rng = CurFunc.getParent()->createRNG(this);
  llvm::errs() << (*rng)() << '\n';

  return false;
}
```

Now you can run this on a module like this (assuming you modified the `hello world` pass from the [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#quick-start-writing-hello-world)):

```
opt -load ./libLLVMHelloPass.so -hello foo.bc -o bar.bc
```

Rerunning this, it will give you the same pseudo-random number.

The `-rng-seed` option becomes available to your pass once you include the header (and link against the `LLVM` support library, i.e. `llvm-config --libfiles support`). So, changing the above execution line to something like:

```
opt -load ./libLLVMHelloPass.so -hello -rng-seed 42 foo.bc -o bar.bc
```

should give a different sequence.

Lastly, AFAIK, `LLVM` passes via `opt` are run sequentially in the context of a `PassManager` (certainly for the legacy one). I believe one should adhere to that advice when building a custom standalone `LLVM` tool using multi-threading (in other words, not intended to be run by `opt`). For relevant examples of standalone apps using the `LLVM` API have a look into the unit tests source subdir (one hint is to look for `.cpp` files that have a `main()`, although they are not always set up like that).

Comment: An example of the RNG implementation I was referring to is DuplicateBB from the llvm-dev-meeting-tutorial github. However my implementation was much different, as was my understanding of the RandomNumberGenerator. You're explanation cleared that up, thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, I've seen that Quarkslab tutorial. I still couldn't recall any time I've used this API class.